# Server error when attempting to access "All actions" subtab of my meta profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, profile-page

I'm trying to access the "All actions" subtab of my user profile on this site (Interpersonal Skills Meta), but when I try to do so, I get a server error: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/11936/gparyani

I've tried accessing the same tab on other sites, including per-site metas, but it only seems to happen here on this per-site meta and not on any other site.

Comment: Interesting - I get the same error, both on your profile and my own. But I tried a few other users at random and did not get an error on theirs..

Comment: Meta SE duplicate: [All actions, responses, and votes tabs on my user profile are returning errors (usually)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328451/323179)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this [has just been rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328452/135201).